# Am I using programmatic constraint definitions properly?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

With the newer versions of Hibernate I noticed we could now programmatically define constraints and was wondering if I can use this approach to *dynamically* define constraints.

Essentially my "DynamicValidator" looks like this so far (UnsupportedOperationExceptions for methods that I am unsure of at this time):

```
public abstract class DynamicValidator implements Validator {

    private TypeConstraintMappingContext<?> constraintMappingContext;

    public <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validate(@Nonnull T object, Class<?>... groups) {
        Validator validator = configureValidator(object);
        return validator.validate(object, groups);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validateProperty(T object, String propertyName, Class<?>... groups) {
        Validator validator = configureValidator(object);
        return validator.validateProperty(object, propertyName, groups);
    }

    protected void addConstraint(String property, ConstraintDef<?, ?> constraintDef) {
        constraintMappingContext.property(property, ElementType.METHOD).constraint(constraintDef);
    }

    protected void addConstraint(ConstraintDef<?, ?> constraintDef) {
        constraintMappingContext.constraint(constraintDef);
    }

    protected void addConstraintViolation(String property, String messageTemplate) {
        constraintMappingContext.property(property, ElementType.METHOD).constraint(new NotValidDef().message(messageTemplate));
    }

    protected abstract <T> void defineDynamicConstraints(@Nonnull T object);

    private <T> Validator configureValidator(@Nonnull T object) {
        HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure();
        ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();
        constraintMappingContext = constraintMapping.type(object.getClass());
        defineDynamicConstraints(object);
        return configuration.addMapping(constraintMapping).buildValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validateValue(Class<T> beanType, String propertyName, Object value, Class<?>... groups) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public BeanDescriptor getConstraintsForClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> type) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public ExecutableValidator forExecutables() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

My concern is that I'm essentially generating a new Validator every time I want to validate an object. Is that all right? My instincts tell me that I should be reusing a single validator, but it doesn't seem as though I can configure a validator post creation.

Answer (score 0):

> My instincts tell me that I should be reusing a single validator,

Your instinct is right. In particular `ValidatorFactory` instances are supposed to be cached. They are quite expensive to create. Also by re-building all the time, you effectively need to create the constraint meta data over and over again and cannot make sure of the otherwise cached metadata.

I guess technically what you are doing is possible, but I would advise against it, in particular if performance is one of your concerns.

What is your actual usecase?

Comment: I'd like to reuse and apply constraints to bean properties at runtime/dynamically. Mainly because one constraint may depend on another field. Such as requiring an end date to come after the start date of a bean instance.